# How to bypass a bindkey directive in GNU screen?

Tags: key-bindings, gnu-screen

I use the `bindkey` command in my .screenrc file to make use of the F5 and F6 keys:

```
# Split/restore on F5/F6
bindkey -k k5 split
bindkey -k k6 only
```

However, a few programs use those keys as inputs (like `htop`). Is there a way of bypassing  the GNU screen key bindings so that those keystrokes go to the current terminal?

I've tried `Ctrl-a`, `F5` but that doesn't seem to work. And it doesn't seem to mention anything about bypassing the bindings in the [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_94.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've figured it out.

The [`mapdefault`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_96.html) command is intended for this purpose.

With the following added to the .screenrc file you are able to type `Ctrl-A` `e` `<key>` or `Ctrl-A` `Ctrl-E` `<key>` and have `<key>` sent to the terminal:

```
# It's sometimes useful to have a quote key.
bind ^E mapdefault
bind e mapdefault
```